# Provisioning a VPS - help predicting disk space needs

Tags: blockchain, parity, nodes

I am going to provision a VPS for a Parity ETH node.

Can anyone give me a guess what my disk space needs will need to be for the Parity download of the Mainnet blockchain?

Date is 12 September 2017.  Similar questions exist but the answer changes over time.

Comment: Which network are you going to connect ? Mainnet ? or your private node ?

Comment: Mainnet/ETH.  And these words are because my reply was not accepted.